# Cannot set temp greater than 90 degrees or less than 50 degrees in Google Home App

Tags: google-smart-home

I'm using the TemperatureSettings device trait.
The problem that I'm having is when I try to change manually (not using
voice commands) the set point to a temperature greater than 90 F degrees or
less than 50 F degrees, Google Home app always sends to the server 90
degrees or 50 F degrees in the request (this only happens with Fahrenheit).
If I use voice commands everything works well.

I tried to remove the "thermostatTemperatureRange" attribute to see if the problem was the min and max threshold, but the result is the same, I can only change the temperature to a value greater than 90 degrees or less than 50 degrees if I use voice commands

Comment: Can you open this issue on the Public Issue Tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/) ?